# Groovy scripting in place of shell scripting in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

On this page at github.com describing Best Practices:

https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-examples/blob/master/docs/BEST_PRACTICES.md

Under *"Groovy Gotchas"* It says:

> Don’t use the Groovy scripting in place of shell scripting - work coming for the ability to run a Groovy step on the node as with the normal Groovy plugin build step, but until then, shell out, even if it’s just to do sh 'groovy foo.groovy'.

What does this mean? If I have a whole bunch of groovy code running my pipeline, is this impacting my Jenkins infrastructure in some way? Some people are telling me that Groovy is being interpreted on the master, which is impacting performance. Is this true? How much of an impact can it have?

I have a Jenkinsfile that is loading a Pipeline Library, and the library has a number of utilities that contain a bunch of code that performs tasks. Is this no good? Do i have to go back to a series of shell scripts?

If anyone has some concrete information about why this entry is in the best practices file, please let me know!

Comment: If you have a working setup, I'm sure it is fine. :)